# How does a moving observer respond to time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

James and Toni both have got the following apparatus.

[image]

Initially, both are at rest. They've found that it takes 1 second for light from the laser to just touch the mirror. Now, James is on a train moving at a velocity ***v*** while Toni is still at rest. Both turn on their lasers at the same time. Toni sees the light touches the mirror of his apparatus earlier than James's.

Now, from James's frame of reference, it is Toni who is moving with velocity ***v*** while he is at rest. Applying the same argument as in the previous case, can't we say that in his reference, light touches James's mirror earlier than Toni's?

What can be the explanation?

Comment: Don't trust the obvious when dealing with speeds near the speed of light.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not forget that not only time but also order of events is relative.
So indeed Toni sees his light touch his mirror first while James sees his light tough his mirror first.

Answer (score 0):

The situation that you show is different from that used in the typical derivation of time dilation where observer B's light clock is moving with respect to observer A and therefore B's time interval is a proper time interval whereas A's is not. So A finds that B's time interval for a pulse of the light clock is smaller than his time interval. Note that B cannot simply reverse this and apply time dilation to A's time interval as it is not a proper time interval - in A's frame the two events, light emission and light hitting the mirror occur at two different x-values.

In your example, the time intervals that you are considering are proper time intervals in each frame. So Toni's measurement of the time interval for one pulse of James' light clock is larger than James' time interval measurement. But equally, James' measurement of the time interval for one pulse of Toni's light clock is larger than Toni's time interval measurement. (I'm not sure of your wording that one is seeing something earlier than the other).